# ubuntu 12.10: rdp from windows 7 renders empty desktop - common fix doesn't work

Tags: 12.10, gnome-session, xrdp

When I use 'Remote Desktop Connection' in Windows 7 to connect to my Ubuntu 12.10 machine with xRdp installed, I can login, but the only thing I get after logging in is an empty desktop.

I found that many people could fix this by creating a .xsession -file in their home-directory, with following command: `gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d`

I tried it, but it doesn't work.

When I try that command from the terminal, it gives the following:
A messagebox:

```
 Could not acquire name on session bus
```

A WARNING in the terminal:

```
 Failed to acquire org.gnome.SessionManager
```

Any help greatly appreciated!